# Construct any bipartite graph with degree constraints

Tags: algorithm, graph

We need to construct a bipartite graph with N vertices each, on the two parts, and with total number of edges equal to M.

- The vertices on the left are numbered from 1 to N.
- The vertices on the right are also numbered from 1 to N.
- The degree of every vertex to be greater than or equal to X, and to be lesser than or equal to Y. i.e. for all v, X ≤ deg(v) ≤ Y

Given four integers N, M, X, Y we need to construct some bipartite graph satisfying this property. If there does not exist any such graph, then also tell the same.

Example : 
If N=2 , M=3 , X=1 and Y=2
then the 3 edges in bipartite graph will be : (1,1),(2,2) and (1,2)

If N=2 , M=3 , X=1 and Y=1 then no bipartite graph exists.

How can this problem be solved if

```
1 ≤ N ≤ 100
1 ≤ X ≤ Y ≤ N 
0 ≤ M ≤ N * N
```

Original question [link](https://www.codechef.com/ACMIND16/problems/ICPC16F)

Comment: Nice problem. Please show what you have done till now.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal So, the point is assuming we want to have degree between these two constraints, so we can sequentially map a vertex from left to X vertices on right. and then try to assign to whole remaining vertices. And again incrementing one more edge to sum them up to M. But  its becoming very complex. So was thinking if there is some trivial way that am missing

Comment: A (possible) direction to think can be: Think in terms of the transportation problem where you have n sources, n destinations (along with some extra constraints on capacity/demand).

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Bit more explanation will help. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the variables need to satisfy:

```
X * N <= M <= Y * N
```

Otherwise, there will be no solution.

Finding the edges could be done in waves. Start by connecting each node `i` from the first set to the according node `i` from the second set. In the next wave, connect `i` with `(i + 1) mod N`. Then `i` with `(i + 2) mod N` and so one. This will increase the degree of each vertex by exactly one in each wave. Stop whenever you have constructed `M` edges. This may also happen during a wave.

Answer (score 0):

ACM ICPC 2016 India Preliminary Round Problem.

[Link](https://www.codechef.com/ACMIND16/problems/ICPC16F)

The contest is now ended. I couldn't submit the answer (was about to submit the code just 10 secs before the end and my Internet stopped working).

`d` is equivalent to `X` in the OP's version of the problem.

`D` is equivalent to `Y` in the OP's version of the problem.

`t` is the number of test cases.

I made the code as per the original question in the link.

The logic is similar to 
[Nico Schertler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40194613/3160529)'s one. My complexity will be a little more because instead of just connecting, `i+x`th node to `i` in the `x`th iteration, I have used a set that finds the first element not connected in the range `[1..N]` and connects them.

This is my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int main() {

    int t, n, m, d, D;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--) {
        cin >> n >> m >> d >> D;
        if(n*D < m || n*d > m)
            printf("-1\n");
        else {
            vector <set <int> > v(n);
            int edges = 0, count = 0;
            while(count != d) {
                for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                        if(v[i].find(j) == v[i].end()) {
                            v[i].insert(j);
                            ++edges;
                            break;
                        }
                        if(edges == m)
                            break;
                    }
                    if(edges == m)
                        break;
                }   
                ++count;
            }

            while(edges < m) {
                for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    if(v[i].size() == D)
                        continue;
                    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                        if(v[i].find(j) == v[i].end()) {
                            v[i].insert(j);
                            ++edges;
                            break;
                        }
                        if(edges == m)
                            break;
                    }
                    if(edges == m)
                        break;
                }
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                set <int>::iterator it = v[i].begin();
                for(; it != v[i].end(); ++it) {
                    printf("%d %d\n", i+1, (*it)+1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know whether this code is correct or not.